# How to remove or disable the breakpoint field in xcode?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

When I want to close or open a function in xcode I always accidentally add a breakpoint, that is very annoying so I wonder if there is a way to remove/disable it. I have searched for a solution but they are just people asking how to remove a breakpoint. I have checked through all the settings but not found anything. Or maybe there is an option to change how to add breakpoints like double click to add as in eclipse?

Here is an image of what Im talking about:

[image]

Comment: just move your mouse over the break point and click on it, it will disable the break point function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any thing in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist to help. But there are always the keyboard shortcuts for Fold and Unfold

[image]